# Determine if the solutions to a non-linear system is a subspace

Tags: systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I have a system of non-linear equations:

$$x+y^3-2z=0$$

$$x+y=0$$

And I want to know if the solutions to this system is a subspace in $\mathbb R^3.$

I know that the solutions of a homogeneous linear system is a subspace in $\mathbb R^3.$ , but I am not sure if this still applies for a non-linear system. Could someone teach me how to determine whether the solutions to this system is a subspace or not?

Comment: $(1,-1,0)$ is a solution but $(2,-2,0)$ is not.

Comment: What are the conditions that should be satisfied when we deal with a linear subspace?

Comment: a linear subspace has to contain zero vector, and is closed under addition and scalar multiplication. But like what Antonie had said, I can only satisfy the first equation, and fail to satisfy the second equation with the same solution.